# PHP react parallel requests

Tags: php, multithreading, websocket, ratchet

I have an app which communicate through websocket with my server. I am using Ratchet and everything works perfect. The next thing i want to implement is to make requests to some other server and push responses through websocket to clients. My question is how to make parallel requests with react. Let say i have 5 endpoints which response i want to get parallel (thread). I want to call each endpoint every .2s for example and send response to websocket server clients. For example (this is just demonstration code):

```
$server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(.2, function ($timer) {
    curl('endpoint1');
});

$server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(.2, function ($timer) {
    curl('endpoint2');
});

$server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(.2, function ($timer) {
    curl('endpoint3');

});
```

But this timer does not work this way. Is it even possible to achive this with react?

Im am not showing websocket code because communication between clients works nice.

Comment: Since you need those pages loaded every 0.2 seconds would it be possible to connect those pages to your websocket and whenever those pages update to send the update to all connections that need it?

Answer (score 0):

To start. "**React (Ratchet)**" - operate in one thread mode (feature libevent). That is, anything that will block the process - bad idea... Curl request - will stop work socket server until it receives a response.

For your application - I would use **ZMQ**.
The point is this:

- you run worker process (for example: ZMQWorker),
- your server sends curl-data on *ZMQWorker* (via ZMQ).
- *ZMQWorker* send Curl request
- after sending the request, *ZMQWorker* send a response to the *WebSocket*
  (via ZMQ). It you can get via **reactphp/zmq**

If you need to send a lot of concurrent requests - You will need **pthread** library - it provides multi-threading.

I've also heard that it is possible to provide work pthread + libevent, but personally I did not do.

P.S *But the use of architecture ZMQ, you get a distributed architecture, to the same scalable!*